# How to perform logical indexing of cell array for sparse matrix in coordinate format?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Let `A` be a sparse matrix in coordinate format `[row(int) col(int) val(float)]`. If a upper triangular sparse matrix of `A` is needed, then the same can be obtained using logical indexing like:

```
A = A(A(:,1) <= A(:,2), :);
```

If A is cell array `[{row(int)} {col(int)} {val(string)}]`, how do I perform the same logical indexing as above in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cell2mat` to transform a column of the cell into a matrix that can be used as an index list:

```
A={1,2,'top';2,1,'bottom'}
A = 
    [1]    [2]    'top'   
    [2]    [1]    'bottom'
>> A(cell2mat(A(:,1))<=cell2mat(A(:,2)),:)
ans = 
    [1]    [2]    'top'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
A = A(cellfun(@(x,y) x>=y, A(:,1),A(:,2)),:);
```

That should only keep the rows in which the value in the first column is greater than or equal to the value in the second column. You can change the `x>=y` comparison to anything you want, including string comparisons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using matlab built-in sparse matrix format?

Create a sparse matrix:

```
>> A=sparse([1 2],[2 1],1,2,2)
A =
   (2,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
```

Extract upper triangular part:

```
>> triu(A)
ans =
   (1,2)        1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and question. I can't use matlab built-in sprase matrix format because the values are all strings.